# Write in column 2 of of a listview only?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview

I have two columns in my listView, lets call them Column1, and Column2.

Is it possible to add a bunch of items to column2 only, and make it so those items only go strictly under column2 and not column1?

When I add items it adds an item to Column2, and Column1 and I don't want that.

How would I go about doing this?

Here's some of my test code. I made an array with two strings. I want both of those strings to go under column2 (each in their own row) and not under column1. When I test it, they still go under column2 AND column1 which is what I don't want.

```
string[] h = {"Hi","Hello"};
listViewGoogleInsight.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(h));
```

---

Heres the code Im trying to do now. The first portion adds items to column1, the second part adds items to column 2. So far it is making a lot of blank spaces under column 2 before showing the column 2 items  [link](http://content.screencast.com/users/kytro360/folders/Jing/media/838ca0aa-f132-4cb8-b72c-c863ee3956bb/2012-11-05_2052.png) . How do I fix this?:

```
string[] n = getBetweenAll(site, "('rising drilldown', '", "');\"");
         foreach (string s in n) 
         listViewGoogleInsight.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(s));


string[] u = getBetweenAll(site, "<td class=\"trends-hbars-value\">", "</td>");

         foreach (var greeting in u)
         {
             var item = new ListViewItem();

             item.SubItems.Add(greeting);

             listViewGoogleInsight.Items.Add(item);
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I used a ListView, but I think something like this would do what you want...

```
string[] h = {"Hi","Hello"};

foreach (var greeting in h)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem();

    item.SubItems.Add(greeting);

    listViewGoogleInsight.Items.Add(item);
}
```

If that doesn't do it exactly, read up on the `SubItems` property - it's probably what you need to know about.

**EDIT:** Assuming the rows have already been added, try this loop instead...

```
for (int i = 0; i < h.Length; i++)
{
    listViewGoogleInsight.Items[i].SubItems.Add(h[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hey the code worked, but when I try to implement it with other code which adds code only to column 1, it creates extra spaces in column 2. Anyway I can make it so its all aligned?

Heres a pic of the issue: [link](http://content.screencast.com/users/kytro360/folders/Jing/media/838ca0aa-f132-4cb8-b72c-c863ee3956bb/2012-11-05_2052.png)

Comment: One last question. When I run it I get this error, any idea why?: InvalidArgument=Value of '7' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Comment: And the error points to this line:    listViewGoogleInsight.Items[i].SubItems.Add(u[i]);

Comment: It sounds like the number of items in the `u` array is greater than the number of rows in the list.  You should be able to prevent the error by changing the loop from `i < h.Length;` to `i < h.Length && i < listViewGoogleInsight.Items.Count;`.  This will stop the loop when either the end of the array is reached or the last row is reached, whichever comes first.